# Selenium can't click on element, because of overlay

Tags: java, selenium, scroll, selenium-chromedriver

I can't click on element, because of overlay appears. Try to use capability to scroll to element and set it in bottom. Does not work for me.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR, 1);
RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Can we do it in another way using java, chrome options (except js)?

> chromedriver 2.36
>
> selenium 3.11.0
>
> testNG 6.14.2

Comment: How does `can't click` relate to `ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR`? What is your exact _usecase_? Update the question with the relevant _HTML_, your code trials and error stack trace

Comment: For capabilities, just check https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities. It gives all the answers you need.

Comment: @Sasugasm, thanks. I have already checked it. elementScrollBehavior doesn't work in chrome

Comment: @DebanjanB is absolutely right !  ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR has nothing to do with click ! share your use case and relevant HTML code !

Comment: What element is overlaying the one you want to click?  Is it an invisible web element meant to prevent user interaction that is temporary and will remove after a certain time, or is it a drop-down window that covers a button?  If you can't provide the other info requested can you at least elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1):

If something overlays on top of the element you want to click then use actions method to move to the element which will make it enable to click and then click. This should work:

```
Actions actions1 = new Actions(driver);
actions1.moveToElement(youElement);
actions1.click();
actions1.build().perform();
```

Comment: this did not work for me.  It's enabled and "clickable" but clicking it doesn't do anything until the overlay is removed.